# vb.net textbox not using the password character setting

Tags: vb.net

I have a textbox in Visual Studio 2005 with the PasswordChar property set to `*`. However, when I check it I still see the text like normal. I expected to only see `*` characters. I'm running Windows XP. Any ideas?

```
    'PasswordTextBox
    '
    Me.PasswordTextBox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(131, 93)
    Me.PasswordTextBox.Multiline = True
    Me.PasswordTextBox.Name = "PasswordTextBox"
    Me.PasswordTextBox.PasswordChar = Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(42)
    Me.PasswordTextBox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(207, 25)
    Me.PasswordTextBox.TabIndex = 3
```

Comment: Are you using a TextBox object, or a PasswordBox object?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.aspx Also, is this WinForms, or ASP.NET, or what?

Comment: @JamDara please post your winform designer code in InitializeComponent()

Comment: eeewwwww winforms.....

Answer (score 2):

I guess you set multiline.

> If the Multiline property is set to true, setting the PasswordChar property has no visual effect

Full remark from MSDN:

> Remarks
>
> The UseSystemPasswordChar property has precedence over the PasswordChar property. 
>   Whenever the UseSystemPasswordChar is set to true, the default system password 
>   character is  used and any character set by PasswordChar is ignored.
>
> If the Multiline property is set to true, setting the PasswordChar property has no 
>   visual effect. When the PasswordChar property is set to true, cut, copy, 
>   and paste actions in the control using the keyboard cannot be performed, 
>   regardless of whether the Multiline property is set to true or false.

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: you should not guess in answer

Comment: Please the link to the [reference where you extract this excerpt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: @Vikas - as OP didn't (or hasn't yet) provided additional clarification, this is a reasonable answer.

Comment: To clarify why I think this is a reasonable answer is that it's a good guess based on what OP did include in their question (at least originally) - VS 2005 (which means most likely .NET 2.0), which in turn means either ASP.NET Web Forms or Win Forms.  Web Forms TextBox doesn't have a property `PasswordChar`, but Win Forms `TextBox` does.

Comment: @QWR .. Tested on VS2005 multiline does not affect to Password Char

Comment: `When the PasswordChar property is set to true, cut, copy, and paste actions in the control using the keyboard cannot be performed, regardless of whether the Multiline property is set to true or false.` Multine only affect for Framework 2.0, the rest or frameworks it does not affect.